# Print a json file from php into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('getfile.php', function(data) {
alert(data);
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my php file-->getfile.php

```
<?php
$json='{"info":{"name":"ram","lname":"katara"}}';
$json = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($json);
?>
```

my output is-->

```
Array ( [info] => Array ( [name] => ram [lname] => katara ) )
```

How can i print this json data into my html page using javascript or ajax jquery.

Comment: Just echo the first line in your PHP, you don't need to decode or use print_r. Just `echo '{"info":{"name":"ram","lname":"katara"}}';`.

Comment: You do realize you're sending an array (`PHP`) and not json data as you're decoding it `json_decode()`. The real question here is **What would you like to do with the json data you receive from your php script?**

Comment: @Darren Question is definitely not well described, i agree, i think you need to json_encode(), see the answer and try it out.

Comment: even if i use json_encode(). i am not getting my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the opposite you would do normally, take  PHP objects and encode them into JSON.

**php**

```
$data=array('info'=>array('name'=>'ram',
                         'lname'=>'katara'
           ));
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json; //{"info":{"name":"ram","lname":"katara"}}
```

**Js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('getfile.php', function(json) {
     $('#print').html('<p>First Name: ' + json.info.name + '</p>');
     $('#print').append('<p>Last Name : ' + json.info.lname + '</p>');
  });
});
</script>

<div id="print"></div>
```

Comment: i want this data to be printed in another html file using javascript jquery or ajax..

Comment: See the below answer..!

Comment: @raviG I expanded on my answer

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to put value of a php variable into javascript. For that, follow this:

Define your `$json` as global variable, at the top.

And in the Javascript:

```
<script> 

  var json = <?php echo $json; ?> ;   

</script>
```

Edit: You need to `json_encode($json);` instead of `json_decode()` ... this should output in correct format, then you can alert in Javascript however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes AJAX query is a way to ask for data from a php file on the server to a HTML file.

The simplest POST AJAX query structure is below (you can use GET also):

```
$.POST("getfile.php",function(data) { 
    if(!data) {
       alert("No data received"); }
    else {
       $("YourOutputDivfromHTML").innerHTML += ......; //what ever to display from the response
       // or alert();

});
```

In the php file you should:

> echo json_encode($json);